# C#-MongoDB: List inside the Where Clause with OR operator

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, lambda, dynamicquery

I have a list of categories, and i am creating a dynamic query.

```
var Categories = GetCategories(); //list of string
query = query.Where(x => x.CategoryID == ?????);
```

Now how can i make the categories list have an OR operator on each category inside the where clause?

Like for example, lets assume Categories list has two categories.
So it will be like:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.CategoryID == Categories[0] | x.CategoryID == Categories[1]);
```

but this has to be dynamic.

Comment: What does `GetCategories()` return? What *kind* of data?

Answer (score 1):

you could do it like this

```
query.Where(x => Categories.Contains(x.CategoryID))
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by a dynamic query

Comment: Generating queries on runtime. Thats the exception its throwing

Comment: `Contains` should work for in-memory list and should be translated into `$in` MongoDB operator. Can you share your error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use [Expression Trees (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/)

> Expression trees represent code in a tree-like data structure, where
>   each node is an expression, for example, a method call or a binary
>   operation such as x < y.
>
> **You can compile and run code represented by expression trees. This
>   enables dynamic modification of executable code, the execution of LINQ
>   queries in various databases, and the creation of dynamic queries.** For
>   more information about expression trees in LINQ, see [How to use expression trees to build dynamic queries (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries).

Here is a very simple example to start from:

> The following code example demonstrates how to compile an expression tree and run the resulting code.
>
> ```
>     // Creating an expression tree.  
>     Expression<Func<int, bool>> expr = num => num < 5;  
>
>     // Compiling the expression tree into a delegate.  
>     Func<int, bool> result = expr.Compile();  
>
>     // Invoking the delegate and writing the result to the console.  
>     Console.WriteLine(result(4));  
>
>     // Prints True.  
>
>     // You can also use simplified syntax  
>     // to compile and run an expression tree.  
>     // The following line can replace two previous statements.  
>     Console.WriteLine(expr.Compile()(4));  
>
>     // Also prints True.
> ```

Here is an example of how to use expression trees to build dynamic queries [How to use expression trees to build dynamic queries (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries):

> The following example shows you how to use expression trees to
>   construct a query against an IQueryable data source and then execute
>   it. The code builds an expression tree to represent the following
>   query:
>
> ```
>    companies.Where(company => (company.ToLower() == "coho winery" ||
>        company.Length > 16))
>           .OrderBy(company => company)
> ```
>
> The factory methods in the System.Linq.Expressions namespace are used
>   to create expression trees that represent the expressions that make up
>   the overall query. The expressions that represent calls to the
>   standard query operator methods refer to the Queryable implementations
>   of these methods. The final expression tree is passed to the
>   CreateQuery(Expression) implementation of the provider of
>   the IQueryable data source to create an executable query of type
>   IQueryable. The results are obtained by enumerating that query
>   variable.
>
> ```
> // Add a using directive for System.Linq.Expressions.  
>
> string[] companies = { "Consolidated Messenger", "Alpine Ski House", "Southridge Video", "City Power & Light",  
>                    "Coho Winery", "Wide World Importers", "Graphic Design Institute", "Adventure Works",  
>                    "Humongous Insurance", "Woodgrove Bank", "Margie's Travel", "Northwind Traders",  
>                    "Blue Yonder Airlines", "Trey Research", "The Phone Company",  
>                    "Wingtip Toys", "Lucerne Publishing", "Fourth Coffee" };  
>
> // The IQueryable data to query.  
> IQueryable<String> queryableData = companies.AsQueryable<string>();  
>
> // Compose the expression tree that represents the parameter to the predicate.  
> ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "company");  
>
> // ***** Where(company => (company.ToLower() == "coho winery" || company.Length > 16)) *****  
> // Create an expression tree that represents the expression 'company.ToLower() == "coho winery"'.  
> Expression left = Expression.Call(pe, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));  
> Expression right = Expression.Constant("coho winery");  
> Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);  
>
> // Create an expression tree that represents the expression 'company.Length > 16'.  
> left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(string).GetProperty("Length"));  
> right = Expression.Constant(16, typeof(int));  
> Expression e2 = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);  
>
> // Combine the expression trees to create an expression tree that represents the  
> // expression '(company.ToLower() == "coho winery" || company.Length > 16)'.  
> Expression predicateBody = Expression.OrElse(e1, e2);  
>
> // Create an expression tree that represents the expression  
> // 'queryableData.Where(company => (company.ToLower() == "coho winery" || company.Length > 16))'  
> MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(  
>     typeof(Queryable),  
>     "Where",  
>     new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType },  
>     queryableData.Expression,  
>     Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(predicateBody, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));  
> // ***** End Where *****  
>
> // ***** OrderBy(company => company) *****  
> // Create an expression tree that represents the expression  
> // 'whereCallExpression.OrderBy(company => company)'  
> MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(  
>     typeof(Queryable),  
>     "OrderBy",  
>     new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType, queryableData.ElementType },  
>     whereCallExpression,  
>     Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string>>(pe, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));  
> // ***** End OrderBy *****  
>
> // Create an executable query from the expression tree.  
> IQueryable<string> results = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(orderByCallExpression);  
>
> // Enumerate the results.  
> foreach (string company in results)  
>     Console.WriteLine(company);  
>
> /*  This code produces the following output:  
>
>     Blue Yonder Airlines  
>     City Power & Light  
>     Coho Winery  
>     Consolidated Messenger  
>     Graphic Design Institute  
>     Humongous Insurance  
>     Lucerne Publishing  
>     Northwind Traders  
>     The Phone Company  
>     Wide World Importers  
> */
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution helps in case my original answer suggesting using Expression Trees is not useful:

**The code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp39
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct CategoryEntry {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var categories = new List<CategoryEntry>();
            categories.Add(new CategoryEntry() { Id = 1, Description = "1-First"});
            categories.Add(new CategoryEntry() { Id = 1, Description = "1-Second" });
            categories.Add(new CategoryEntry() { Id = 2, Description = "2-First" });
            categories.Add(new CategoryEntry() { Id = 3, Description = "3-First" });

            var categoryIDs = new HashSet<int>();
            categoryIDs.Add(1);
            categoryIDs.Add(2);

            Console.WriteLine("The sought Ids \n");
            foreach (var categoryId in categoryIDs) {
                Console.WriteLine(categoryId);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            // returns a collection of collections, one collection per queried category id
            var result = categoryIDs.Select(id => categories.FindAll(c => c.Id == id));
            Console.WriteLine("The result from the variable result \n");
            foreach (var collection in result)
            {
                collection.ForEach(entry => Console.WriteLine(entry.Description));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            // returns a single collection with all found categories for all queried categories ids 
            var flatResult = categoryIDs.SelectMany(id => categories.FindAll(c => c.Id == id));
            Console.WriteLine("The result from the variable flatResult \n");
            foreach (var entry in flatResult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Description);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**The output**

The sought Ids

1
2

The result from the variable result

1-First
1-Second
2-First

The result from the variable flatResult

1-First
1-Second
2-First

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this and it worked.

```
var subChildCategories = GetChildCategories(Convert.ToInt32(getProductsDomainModel.CategoryID));
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(FullProductDomainModel));
BinaryExpression binaryExpression = null;

foreach (var category in subChildCategories)
{
    var prop = Expression.Property(parameter, "CategoryID");
    var value = Expression.Constant(category.ToString());
    var newBinary = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, prop, value);

    binaryExpression =
        binaryExpression == null
        ? newBinary
        : Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Or, binaryExpression, newBinary);
}

var cookedExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<FullProductDomainModel, bool>>(binaryExpression, parameter).Compile();

query = query.Where(cookedExpression).AsQueryable();
```